# Unable to build poky recipes: /poky/meta/recipes-core/ncurses/ncurses_6.0+20171125.bb:do_install failed

Tags: kernel, yocto, ncurses, bitbake

I am trying to build the meta-altera layer recipes from Altera FPGA, but it seems I am unable to bake the poky recipes-core/ncurses recipe.

I am seeing the error message

> ERROR: Task
> (virtual:native:/home/jfrye/Developer/Altera/Playground/poky/meta/recipes-core/ncurses/ncurses_6.0+20171125.bb:do_install)
> failed with exit code '1' NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 269 tasks of
> which 246 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.

This same error occurs when I try to build their bootloader and kernel. I am assuming since it is part of poky/meta layer that it has nothing to do with their layer. Is it required that I install libncurses6 in order to build this? I cannot be sure but I think that could be an issue, although I am not an expert with Yocto and BitBake and am not sure how dependencies on my OS would effect the build. As a side note, I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and libcurses6 does not seem to be part of the packager for this version.

Is there any chance it is a versioning issue with the poky git?

I am following this guide
https://rocketboards.org/foswiki/Documentation/YoctoDoraBuildWithMetaAltera
so I believe that I am using the sumo branch, but it looks like the last updates to that branch were made a while ago.

I looked back at the issue. I think it is something wrong the with libncurses build.
This is the message right before it errs out in the log.

> | installing
> home/jfrye/Developer/Altera/Playground/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/ncurses-native/6.0+20171125-r0/image/home/jfrye/Developer/Altera/Playground/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/ncurses-native/6.0+20171125-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/share/man/man1/tic.1
>
> |installing
> /home/jfrye/Developer/Altera/Playground/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/ncurses-native/6.0+20171125-r0/image/home/jfrye/Developer/Altera/Playground/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/ncurses-native/6.0+20171125-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/share/man/man1/toe.1
>
> | installing
> /home/jfrye/Developer/Altera/Playground/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/ncurses-native/6.0+20171125-r0/image/home/jfrye/Developer/Altera/Playground/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/ncurses-native/6.0+20171125-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/share/man/man1/tput.1
>
> | .. installing alias reset.1
>
> | installing
> /home/jfrye/Developer/Altera/Playground/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/ncurses-native/6.0+20171125-r0/image/home/jfrye/Developer/Altera/Playground/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/ncurses-native/6.0+20171125-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/share/man/man1/tset.1
>
> | .. installing alias reset.1
>
> | ? missing rename for user_caps.5
>
> |installing
> /home/jfrye/Developer/Altera/Playground/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/ncurses-native/6.0+20171125-r0/image/home/jfrye/Developer/Altera/Playground/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/ncurses-native/6.0+20171125-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/share/man/man5/user_caps.5
>
> | installing
> /home/jfrye/Developer/Altera/Playground/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/ncurses-native/6.0+20171125-r0/image/home/jfrye/Developer/Altera/Playground/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/ncurses-native/6.0+20171125-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/share/man/man3/wresize.3ncurses
>
> | make[1]: Leaving directory
> '/home/jfrye/Developer/Altera/Playground/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/ncurses-native/6.0+20171125-r0/build/narrowc/man'
>
> | make: Leaving directory
> '/home/jfrye/Developer/Altera/Playground/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/ncurses-native/6.0+20171125-r0/build/narrowc'
>
> | ERROR: oe_runmake failed

Not sure if this offers any insight into what might be going on, but I am pretty sure it is not a source control issue.

Issue also mentioned on this embedded Linux forum

https://forum.rocketboards.org/t/problem-with-building-yocto-ncurses-shell-do-install-failed/738

Answer (score 0):

let you version control to point to different url for ncurser if asked of the original url.

for ex: if using git

## git url for url this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just missing dependencies here. You didn't reference reading the quick start guide, which details how to get Ubuntu in a state to use Yocto.

https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.8/yocto-project-qs/yocto-project-qs.html

Check the "The Packages" section, and try there. If that doesn't help, reply, and I'll take another look.

Comment: I installed all packages listed. It does not list libncurses-6.0. I have tried with no avail to install that onto my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS host, but I am not sure whether that would even make a difference. I looked at section 5.6.4 "5.6.4. Binary Configuration Scripts Disabled", which mentions ncurses but did not know how to interpret it

Comment: Following the same tutorial, did what you suggested having the same issue. Please help!

Comment: @triplebig, what distribution and version are you using? Also, what's the error?